# Displaying rates: green if the rate has increased, red if the rate has descreased

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put together a website that displays crypto currency rates and I don't even know where to begin for this aspect I'm trying to add to it. If possible, I'd like to code the text for each rate to change colors when you mouse over. A simple hover, yet I'd like the color change to be dynamic. If the rate has recently gone up, it'll show as green when you mouse over it, if it has gone down it will display as red. Again, no idea what all would be involved with that but help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: post some code, there are many ways of doing this the simplist way would probably just to add classes (up/down, red/green.. whatever) to the data as you are pulling it to your webpage. Without any knowledge of how you are attempting this makes it difficult

Comment: Good point, I'm doing the HTML/CSS. I'll ask my partner whose doing the PHP to pull all the data through API and get back to you on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:hover` selector of CSS, probably the easiest way...

HTML

```
<span class="red">If you hover me, I will become red</span> <br>
<span class="green">If you hover me, I will become green</span>
```

CSS

```
.red:hover{
   color: red;
}
.green:hover{
   color: green;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ya4p/)